# Docker web application using Container IP addresse

Tags: docker, localhost

I'm asking how I can get my docker app application work/connect on a **172.17.0.x**.

Because now the url is http://127.0.0.1:8040/my_app.

I need to know why there is **127.0.0.1** and not **172.17.0.x** ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the IP address associated to a container with `docker inspect`, and directly with :

```
docker inspect -f "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" container_name
```

The application is already listening on a port on the IP address of the container (172.17.0.x), and the port on localhost is forwarded to it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i already know the ip adresse of the container and my question is how to get my container run on this ip address not localhost. the container ip address is 172.17.0.3 but my web app work using localhost.